# What is difference between minDate and startDate - datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Which one is correct. And what exactly difference between?

```js
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate());
  $('#date').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    minDate: today
  });
}
```

and

```js
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  today.setDate(today.getDate());
  $('#date').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false,
    startDate: today
  });
}
```

Comment: You've tagged Bootstrap DateTimePicker, but are you sure you're using that library? It has neither of the settings you mention

Comment: Can you select a date less than minDate?  If not thats the difference.

Comment: The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to select date before `minDate`. Startdate is just an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

in `jquery-datetimepicker-2.5.21`,

You are not allowed to select a date before `startDate` and `minDate` does not work